# .ApiClient.Model.Rate cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I getting the following error, How can i solve this?

> ApiClient.Model.Rate cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

I think its giing while serializing but i trid issue was not resolved, please let me know how to solve this.

```
public List<Rate> GetRates(string FromCountry, string FromZip, string ToCountry, string ToCity, string ToState, string ToZip, int PackWeight)
        {
            List<Rate> result = null;
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    result = apiInstance.Rates(apiKey);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    GetServiceError(e, "RatesApi.Rates");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WebMethodResult = ex.Message;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Add a parameterless constructor to `ApiClient.Model.Rate` like `public Rate() {}`

Comment: no i cannot add to ApiClient.Model.Rate, actually, i'm using third party API i need to return list back from web method.

Comment: dirty hack might be in order - made `class HackRate : ApiClient.Model.Rate` and there add `public HackRate () {}` - that might help, or use completely your class instead. Not a good approach in general though

Comment: @Vladimir That won't work, you have to provide the parameters for the base class: `public HackRate() : base(...) {}`

Comment: @Loris156 actually no ) Any Serializer Class need a parameterless constructor because, while deserializing it create an empty new instance, then it copies every public property taken from seialized data. 

We can use any values in the base .ctor - they will be overriden durring the copy phase. But as I sad - it`s poor design.